# There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number: 1628825007

Tags: php, magento, stack-trace

I am very new to magento and i have created a store in localhost and i have added some products also but suddenly when i try to create a new product i gets an error saying:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.  Error log record number: 1628825007

Comment: So: Turn on error reporting and/or look at your error log.

Comment: @MSA check this file (1628825007) under var/reports folder and update the question with error.

Comment: Good generic question that is always being asked with the answer needed which is "We need the actual error message from the stack trace, please use sftp to read the file in `var/report/`, find the file with that number for its name, and post the stack trace contained there within so we can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Error reporting is turned off by default on a new installation of Magento1.  You should find a file (as long as permissions are correct) under your `documentroot/var/report` folder with the same name as the error that has been raised (i.e `1628825007`).  You can open this in any text editor to get a stack trace of the error.  If you can post that back here, hopefully we can help more if you're still stuck.

If you'd prefer to show errors, rather than having to find the file whilst you're in development, you can rename `documentroot/errors/local.sample.xml` to `documentroot/errors/local.xml` and you'll see them displayed instead of hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and resolved by updating PHP to 7.0